# Unity car air-control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a car game, I want to be able to control the car on the air (horizontal only) to the left and right. I have an isGrounded bool to detect if the car is on the air or not and it is properly working. It is a mobile game so i will control the car with the buttons on the screen, here are my normal movement codes. I can simply make the code works both in the ground and air but i dont know how. Can you help me  find any way to make the car move right and left?
I am using this code and call the[functions from this (this is the left button, i have the right button same but with 1 and 0 )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gppN1.png)

```
  
    public void MoveInput(float input){
       horizontal = input; 
    }
      public void MoveButtonRightHandle(bool input){
        if(horizontal == 1){
            carismovingtoright = true;
        }
        else if (horizontal == 0){

            carismovingtoright = false;
             
        } 
    }

    public void MoveButtonLeftHandle(bool input){

      if(horizontal == -1){
             carismovingtoleft = true;
        } else if (horizontal == 0){
            carismovingtoleft = false;
        }
     
    }
    public void BrakeInput(bool input){
       handbrake = input; 
       controller.adjustTraction();
    }
```

Also this is the codes that are related in my controller script

```
 private void moveVehicle(){

            for (int i = 0; i < wheels.Length; i++){
                wheels[i].motorTorque = totalPower / 4;
                wheels[i].brakeTorque = brakPower;
            }

        KPH = rigid.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f;

    }
```